# Ruby: find what was replaced with .sub

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the code

```rb
thisString.sub! /piece\_[0-9]{1,4}.ts/, "piece_#{i}.ts"
```

where `thisString` could be anything from `piece_1.ts` to `piece_9999.ts`

How can I get the number that was replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a numbered capturing group:

```
thisString.sub! /piece\_([0-9]{1,4}).ts/, "piece_#{i}.ts"
```

Now `$1` will give you the value as a string and you can do `$1.to_i`.

You can read more about how this works [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing).

Comment: The idea is that if you surround something in brackets `()`, it will make so that whatever was matched inside the brackets gets assigned to the value of the the given numbered group (this is a regex thing and not Ruby specific). In Ruby, after matching, you can get the value of whatever was matched in the first group with `$1`, second with `$2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As a stopgap, I ended up getting the number first, then doing the sub:

```rb
foundStartPiece = Integer(firstline[/piece\_[0-9]{1,4}.ts/][/[0-9]{1,4}/]) # Returns the number as an integer
```

Edit: After that, I did move to using @ndn's answer

Comment: Note to any beginners like myself: There are many gotchas with leading zeros. This code may significantly break things if it finds `piece_0111.ts` for example.